# Why did I get a Rabbit's Foot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tamed a cat in a Minecraft 1.14 Snapshot, and when I went to sleep without making my cat sit down, it came onto the bed and started purring. It made my screen glitch until I woke up. The cat sat up and I got a Rabbit's Foot, is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 18):

Cats will sometimes give their owners gifts in the morning, including rabbit's feet.

From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cat#Tamed):

> When the player sleeps, tamed cats will go toward their owner and sleep near them. When the player awakes, their tamed cats will also awake. There is a chance that a tamed cat will give the player a gift after they wake up. The gift is a dropped item from the `cat_morning_gift.json` loot table, which contains:
>
> Rabbit's foot
> Rabbit hide
> String
> Rotten flesh
> Feather
> Raw chicken
> Phantom membrane